# Someone please explain this javascript code to me

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

This is the code

looks like the global `user` var is affected by function body

```
var user =  { name: 'Ivan' };

function setUser(user) {
    console.log("asdf", user);
    // user = { name: "asdf", a: 1 }
    user.name = 'Oleg';
    console.log("qwer", user)
}

setUser(user);
```

commented adding `user = { name: "asdf", a: 1 }` changes result

```
function setUser(user) {
    console.log("asdf", user);
    user = { name: "asdf", a: 1 }
    user.name = 'Oleg';
    console.log("qwer", user)
}

setUser(user);

console.log("1234", user, user.name);
```

this is the result ( chrome console )

[image: Result]

Comment: `user.name = 'Oleg';` will mutate the argument if `user` is the argument, and leave the argument unmodified if you reassigned `user` to point to a different object before assigning to `.name`

Comment: Looks like `var user =  { name: 'Ivan' };` and `argument user` are 2 different variables.

It is little bit hard to grasp. But thank you.